# WPF: Command parameter for a delete command in a list

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, command, viewmodel

In my viewmodel, I have a list (ObservableCollection) containing items. In the view, this list is displayed in an `ItemsControl`. In each row, there is a "Delete" button. I want the command behind the button to remove the item from the list.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding myList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        ...
            <Button Command="{StaticResource myDeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="???">
                Remove item
            </Button>
        ...
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

What do I pass as the command parameter?

- The item itself (`Binding .`)? Then I don't have a reference to the list in the command, so I'd need to change my model such that each list item contains a back-reference to the list.
- The list? Then I don't have a reference to the item.
- Both? Then I need to write a MultiConverter that translates the list plus the item into some custom object. Seems like a lot of overhead for such a simple task.

Any ideas? This seems like a fairly common scenario to me, so I guess there must be some well-established best-practice solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've implemented such commands in that way, that I pass the Item as Parameter. The command self knows on which list it should operate. Either trough a delegate that calls a Delete Method in my ViewModel or the command receives the list of items in it's constructor.

i.e. a Command with delegates

```
public sealed class SimpleParameterCommandModel<T> : CommandModel
{
    private readonly Action<T> execute;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> canExecute;

    public SimpleParameterCommandModel(string label, string tooltip, Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute)
        : base(appCtx, dataCtx, label, tooltip)
    {
        if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    ...
}
```

usage:

```
private ICommand _DeleteCommand = null;
public ICommand DeleteCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_DeleteCommand == null)
        {
            _DeleteCommand = new SimpleParameterCommandModel<IEnumerable<DataObjectModel>>                      ("Delete", "Delete selection from data store", 
                (items) => items.ToList().ForEach(i => DeleteItem(i)),
                (items) => items != null && items.Count() > 0 && AllowDelete);
        }
        return _DeleteCommand;
    }
}
public void DeleteItem(DataObjectModel item)
{
        if (item == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("item"); }

    myCollection.Remove(item.Object);
}
```

EDIT: Forgot XAML

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand, ElementName=...}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
        Remove item
</Button>
```

Comment: Danke! :-) Yes, creating a separate Command for each instance of the list is indeed the solution.

Answer (score 4):

First, I would handle the Command in the ViewModel.  I assume that the list that is being used for binding is in the ViewModel, so any code that does "work" on that list should also be done in the ViewModel.

```
class MyViewModel
{ 
    // ... Clipping rest of ViewModel class ...

    private ObservableCollection<MyObject> mMyList = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>(); 
    private ICommand mMyDeleteCommand;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        InitializeMyListSomehow();
        mMyDeleteCommand = new MyCommandClass(
            (item) => DeleteItem(item),
            () => mDeleteCanExecute
        );
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyList
    {
        get { return mMyList; }
        set 
        { 
            // Some function that updates the value and implements INPC
            SetProperty("MyList", ref mMyList, value); 
        }
    }

    public ICommand MyDeleteCommand
    {
        get { return mMyDeleteCommand; }
    }

    void DeleteHandler(var item)
    {
        int index = mMyList.Remove(item);
    }


}
```

Are the items unique?  If so, you could pass the item, and the Delete command handler could look up the item in the list.

If the items are non-unique, you'll have to do a little more logic, depending on the expected outcome.

Now, in the view, your code will look like (notice the StaticResource becomes a Binding):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        ...
            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.MyDeleteCommand,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                              AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                Remove item
            </Button>
        ...
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I don't have a reference to `mMyList` in code. There are multiple such lists displayed in the view.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that the Command is a StaticResource.  In general, in an MVVM solution [it is my understanding that] Commands are handled in the ViewModel, not in the View.  I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, putting the command into the list's viewmodel was indeed the way to go. I accepted Arthur's solution, since he was a bit faster, but yours was extremely helpful as well!